# Get workflow associated list items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, splistitem

I have one requirement to get all the list items which has associated with a particular workflow in SharePoint 2013. Like, I have a designer 2013 workflow with name "Test Workflow" which is added in a custom list. Tis workflow associated with around 70 items. In the same list I've added another workflow with name "Test Workflow 2". I need to fetch the ID of all the list items which are associated with the first workflow (all the 70 items ID).

Answer (score 0):

First of all workflows are attached on list level not item level..

Now regarding your query, you can enable ID column in your "AllItems.aspx" to view   all the 70 items that are associated with first workflow.

I hope you are not looking for any scripted approach to fetch those IDs.